# Easiest way to pack/minify multiple javascript files?

Tags: javascript, compression, minify

I'm looking for a website/program that will let me select multiple javascript files and output their minified versions in the order that they were selected. (E.g code of first selected files on top, last files in the end). Any ideas?

Comment: Not a duplicate as I'm asking specifically for something that supports compressing multiple files

Comment: I agree with you actually. I don't think it's a dupe. Well, ... not of *that* question anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) (and I suspect most of the big JS compressors) already allow for this.

From `java -jar closurecompiler.jar --help`

> --js VAL
>   : The javascript filename. You may
>   specify multiple

Comment: With how long it would take to type up all of that + all the names of the files, i might as well just manually compress each file through a web compresser.

Comment: @Click True. But you could write a simple script that passes files off to closurecompiler to reduce the typing that you'd need.

Comment: I use the online version of Closure compiler, that way i dont have to mess with CMD.
http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

I created a little PHP script to do this check it out :D https://github.com/mario-deluna/packtacular

---

Ed Eliot ([www.ejeliot.com](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/72)) createt a pretty nice php script to pack multiple JavaScript files. I combined his script with the [Jsmin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) class from Douglas Crockford to minify them.

Just Replace

```
foreach ($aFiles as $sFile) {
    $aLastModifieds[] = filemtime("$sDocRoot/$sFile");
    $sCode .= file_get_contents("$sDocRoot/$sFile");
}
```

with

```
foreach ($aFiles as $sFile) {
    $aLastModifieds[] = filemtime("$sDocRoot/$sFile");
    $sCode .= JSMin::minify(file_get_contents("$sDocRoot/$sFile"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) supports that, too (for both JS an CSS files, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the files into a single file (`cat [files] >` or `type [files] >`) before minifying